# how to use multiple match phrases in must with or condition in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

how to use  multiple match phrases in must with or condition  in elastic search?

```
GET questiondetails/question/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "tags.keyword": "azure-data"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "body": "azure-data"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "azure-data"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "answers.body": "azure-data"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "creation_date": {
            "gte": 1584748800,
            "lte": 1585612800
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": "10000"
}
```

tried this query .... I need results in where the word exactly matches in tags  or partial match on body or title or answer.body

But its not working .

Adding comment

GET questiondetails_new/question/_search? { "query": { "bool": { "should": [{ "match_phrase": { "tags.keyword": "azure-data-factory" } }, { "match_phrase": { "title": "azure-data-factory" } } ], "minimum_should_match": 1, "filter": { "range": { "creation_date": { "gte": 1585170170, "lte": 1585170180 } } }

In this query i need all the docs which has exact match as azure-data-factory  or which has azure-data-factory in its titile (String ). It should be an or search .
But its matching with the tags which has the value as azure-data-factory-2 also

Comment: Expectation is to retrieve documents which have "azure-data" in title or body or tags.keyword.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a char filter which will replace "-" with "_" while indexing. You won't need to change  input text(it will work with "-")

```
PUT index38
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "- => _"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "keyword":{
              "type":"keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "keyword":{
              "type":"keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "tags": "azure-data-factory"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "tags": "azure-data-factory"
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "body": "azure-data-factory"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "title": "azure-data-factory"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "answers.body": "azure-data-factory"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": "100"
}
```

If you will analyze text "azure-data-factory" with default analyzer, it will generate 3 tokens ["azure","data","factory"]

```
GET index38/_analyze
{
  "text": "azure-data-factory"
}

Result:

"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "azure",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "data",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "factory",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
```

If you will analyze same text with "my_analyzer" a single token is generated

```
GET index38/_analyze
{
  "text": "azure-data-factory",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}

Result:

"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "azure_data_factory",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
]
```

Comment: One more thing,  i need to serah the exact word including special characters like -.

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli  term search on keyword field does an exact search with whole text. It doesn't match tokens, so above will work

Comment: Not exactly.. I think the problem is with special characters -.
Any idea on how to pass a custom analyzer to a kibana search(Get) query in elastic search. Please suggest.

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli I tested this query "term": {  "tags.keyword": "azure-data"  } it matches with "azure-data" stored in tags field, as fields with keyword type are not analyzed and are stored as it is . Can you give the query which is not working and matching the document

Comment: added my comment in the question  at the end.

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli  my query is different that you posted. Can you try that once my query and let me know which documnet has is wrongly picked/not picked and what is the issue

Comment: Yes. I tried your query.
1. Its picking up the data where its has tags as azure-data-factory
2. Its not considering - and picking data in title which is like below.
How can Azure Data Factory access a Custom Data Connector

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli I have updated answer with my finding . can you point where the result is wrong

Comment: As per my requiremet, none of your inputs should be picked . Because no where it has azure-data alone as a tag and no where it has azure-data as an exact phrase in its title sentence. Need the exact phrase match including -  in tags. No more extra words or letters should be present and title should have the excat phrase (including -) in the sentence.

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli I searched for azure-data-factory , replace "azure-data" in my query to "azure-data-factory". I got your point regarding '-', will pdate query shortly

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli I have updated my answer, you need to reindex data with custom analyzer to handle "-"

Comment: Yes.. I got.. But To an already existing index can we add these mappings?
I am getting the below error.

I am getting below error

        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [title : {analyzer=custom_analyzer, type=text, fields={keyword={type=keyword}}}] [tags : {analyzer=custom_analyzer, type=text, fields={keyword={type=keyword}}}]"

Comment: @JhansiRaniKolapalli You need to re create index